# How does this formula to return the last value in a column work?

Tags: google-sheets

This is a formula which returns last value in a column:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
```

Can't understand how it works because the part `MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))` returns `0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: To see how it would work in the context of the INDEX function (which enables array calculations as @pnuts mentioned), use `=ArrayFormula(MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))` (make sure you put it in a cell in row 1).

Comment: thank you, guys! It works :)! And, I don't understand, why you @AdamL recommend to put it in a cell in row 1. It works in any row for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are absolutely correct, forgot about the MAX bit only returning one result.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of an answer. The segment:

```
=MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))
```

returns `0` if the row it is in has a blank cell in ColumnA, otherwise `1`.

As an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to get:

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
```

returns the row number of the last populated cell in ColumnA.

Simplifying this to an example of three rows with the first (Row1) blank:

the 'not blank' part returns an array of: `FALSE,TRUE,TRUE`
and the ROW part of `1,2,3`

so multiplying (the `*`) these together gives an array `0,2,3` (multiplying by FALSE is equivalent to multiplying by `0` and by TRUE equivalent to times `1`).

The MAX function then selects the largest value (`3`).

The INDEX function then 'reads' the above to return the value in ColumnA in that last (third) row.